# Can't see exposure indicator in viewfinder on Nikon D7000

Tags: nikon, exposure, camera-settings

I can't see that `- <---|---> +` indicator in my viewfinder (I can see it only in manual mode and it used to be everywhere). I went through the whole menu and didn't find anything that may be causing it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
when I cover the lens that indicator shows up. But there's no use for this behavior :)

Comment: Did you enable the virtual horizon? In many Nikons, it takes the place of the exposure indicator.

Comment: @Itai no I didn't. If I do only the horizon will show up. Now I can't see the indicator at all

Comment: I believe you don't see exposure indicator while you are in Aperture or Shutter or any scene mode. You only see this in manual mode.

Comment: @V.B Exactly. But I'm quite sure that it was shown in those modes too. Then I was fiddling with some setting and it disappeared...

Comment: Even when you press the +/- button?

Comment: If you can see it with the lens covered, maybe it is just very dark?

Comment: I know the reason why you see the exposure meter in A or S mode while the lens cap is ON. Reason being at that point of time camera can not compensate either with slow shutter speed if in A mode because its too dark and same in case of S mode with smallest aperture. Otherwise the meter will not be visible as long as camera can adjust the exposure as per available light to correctly expose the photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I too own a Nikon D7000 and never saw the exposure indicator in any mode other than manual.I think it make sense too as if you are in Aperture Priority its the camera that adjust the correct exposure by picking the appropriate shutter speed same is in Shutter Priority.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In Aperture Priority mode, you set a chosen aperture and the camera will automatically match the shutter speed so that a correct exposure is produced (according to the metering mode). The exposure indicator will only be shown if you apply an exposure compensation (hold the +/- button and rotate the command dial). By default the exposure compensation is set to 0 and the indicator is not shown (in P, A, S and auto modes). It will be always shown in M.

Answer (score 2):

In priority modes S and A, the exposure indicator only appears if the camera is incapable of providing an exposed image, like for example if you're in "S" mode and want a super fast shutter but the camera can't chose an aperture that's wide enough because it is limited by lens capability; maybe it needs an f1.8 (very big) and your camera only goes to f4 (average). The meter show up then, to warn you as to HOW underexposed the image is going to be. Hope that helps! (Changing your ISO to a higher number (more sensitive to light) would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So funny, but my D7500 shows some weird behaviour. So the exposure meter shows in M but not A or S unless you apply exposure compensation. That’s with b3 (Easy exposure compensation) OFF. 
With b3 setbto ON the exposure meter is displayed. I had the issue that it showed for S not A until I did a full reset, then it displayed as expected. I was also playing around with reversing the command dials and son on, so I figured the software isn’t quite up to the logic! Lol